# In Azure DevOps, how do I create an Azure Service connection at the organization level rather than the project?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, how do I create an Azure Service connection at the organization level rather than the project?
Everytime I create a new project, I have to create a new Azure Service Connection.

However, I would like to create 1 azure service connection, and allow many projects to use that single connection. This would allow me to re-use this connection. Provision once.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new service connections ui there's an option introduced, which allows "Sharing of service connections across projects".

You have to enable it via Preview features:
[image]

[image]

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for detailed explanations.

Comment: This feature is toggled on for me. Can you please screenshot a demo of a connection that is usable across N number of projects? I’m still not seeing the option anywhere obvious.